# How to call a stored procedure with a mixed-case name from Dapper (with Npgsql)?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, dapper, npgsql

From NuGet, I am using

> ...\packages\Npgsql.2.2.5\lib\net45\Npgsql.dll
>
> ...\packages\Dapper.1.42\lib\net45\Dapper.dll

In calling a stored procedure in PostgreSQL, I have need to preserve the *case of the procedure name* as

```
var x = cnn.Query<icd9>("GetDxLibrary", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I am getting a runtime error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in
>   Npgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR: 42883: function getdxlibrary() does not
>   exist.

If the function in PostgreSQL is renamed to `getdxlibrary()`, all goes well.

How can I call a procedure with a mixed-case name in Dapper?

TIA

Comment: This is another good example why quoted (mixed-case) identifiers are a bad idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But it is so much easier for me to read :)

Comment: That's personal preference, but I find `get_dx_library()` much easier to read then `"GetDxLibrary"()`

Comment: Create a function without quoting its name: `create function FooBar() ...`, then you can use it like you want: `select FooBar(), foobar(), fOoBaR();`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Granted. However, I am inheriting a very extensive list of procedures that has been heavily integrated into EntityFramework. Allowing Pascal Case on the stored procedures will allow use of old code while I change over to Dapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add quotes around your function name:

`var x = cnn.Query<icd9>("\"GetDxLibrary\"", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

PostgreSQL automatically lower-cases all non-quoted identifiers, so when you send it GetDxLibrary it actually sees getdxlibrary.